# How to use applets in intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm a java beginner and I wanna know how to use applets. I've got this little test-program for the paint-applet :

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Main extends Applet {
    public void init() {
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
        g.fillRect(20, 80, 100, 50);
    }
}
```

But in the IDE, "Applet" in the 3rd line has a stripe through it.
And if I try to run the code, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer
```

I'm using IntelliJ as IDE and use jdk14

Can someone help?

Comment: "Java applets were deprecated since Java 9 in 2017 and removed from Java SE 11"  source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet

Comment: "Can someone help?" - The best help we can offer you is to not bother learning how to use applets.  They are a dead-end technology.  The "Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer" - is because that class has been removed.

Comment: _I'm using IntelliJ as IDE and use jdk14_ Is that fourteen (14) or 1.4 (one point four) ?

Comment: Why do you want to learn applets? I suspect you've stumbled across applets, but something else would be more appropriate. You could replace the code you have with a JFrame, and a JPanel pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Applets are deprecated since java 9. You should be using java 8 (jdk 14 does not work)